# Can't put header in text!

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying to put a header but can't seem to figure out how. I've already following instructions for typesetting a header, to no avail.

All the resources I've found on Google point to put something like this

```
usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\rhead{Share\LaTeX}

\lhead{Guides and tutorials}

\rfoot{Page \thepage}
```

Even though I don't get any error, the header won't show. I'm using a template, and the problem is probably there.

Here is the structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} % Formatting packages

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors

\usepackage[big]{layaureo} % Margin formatting of the A4 page, an alternative to layaureo can be \usepackage{fullpage}
% To reduce the height of the top margin uncomment: \addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' % Change the font of the \LaTeX command under the skills section

text

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: If you happen to use windows, you can select the part of your text that's code (but not indented yet) and press ctrl + K, to instantly indent your selection by 4 spaces. I can't confirm how to do this on other operatin systems. :-)

Comment: @1010011010 Cmd+K on Mac OS X.

Comment: Changing the argument of `\pagestyle` to `fancy` in your MWE gives the header and footer here.

Comment: Well what do you expect if you issue `\pagestyle{empty}` in your document?

Comment: Good point. THX problem solved :)

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
```

should be after

```
\begin{document}
```

and you should remove

```
\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering
```

as it not only removes the page numbering, but everything from fancyhdr.

Comment: In addition, if you don't want page numbering on the first page, use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` on the first page and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` on the consequent page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The first chunk of code can be in the preamble, there's no need to place it after `\begin{document}`.